# there's a way to include a minimal WP for check only the current user, its roles (caps?) and then release/free it?

Tags: php, users, 404-error, customization, wp-blog-header.php

I need to count how many times a file in a particular sub-directory is downloaded and track who downloaded it.

I'm using a Php file to do it, it isn't a WP file but I need to include WP to get the current user (if authenticated) and its roles (and maybe caps).

Looking at [Integrating WordPress with Your Website](https://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website) I first used:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../wp-blog-header.php');
```

But then I had a problem with the downloads, returning a error `404 (file not found)`.

Lucky me on the footer of the same Codex article there's this suggestion: [Fixing false 404 headers on external pages including wp-blog-header.php](https://cooltrainer.org/2010/06/20/fixing-false-404-headers-on-external-pages-including-wp-blog-header-php/)

Following the suggestion I just used `init` which seem enough in my case:

```
require_once("../wp-config.php");
$wp->init();
```

Still, looking into `$GLOBALS` I think there's much more done and left than I need.

I'm using `readfile` for the download, the file size maybe *huge*, the user check is done before, the ideal would be to include a minimal WP as fast as possible and release the WP resources just after the user check, before the `readfile`.

So, there's a way to include a minimal WP for check only the current user, its roles (caps?) and then release/free it?

I seen also `wp-load.php` is used and looking/searching around found a lot of *no no* about including all those `wp-*` directly, but all the results where about *including* from a plugin, not my case, do I still need to worry about including directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *no no* about loading wp-* files directly are reasonable when you are developing a WordPress plugin or theme, but if you are developing an external code that require WP (and that seems your case) than you *must* require that files, there is no alternatives.

Consider that including `wp-blog-header.php` is needed when you need to handle WordPress urls, or full WordPress frontend, but when you need WordPress features, including `wp-load.php` is better and faster, and no need to `$wp->init();`.

Also, setting `SHORTINIT` constant to true make the load faster, but doing so some features of WordPress are not available, and the user checking is one of them.

However, requiring few files, and calling a couple of functions you will be able to check user capabilities:

```
<?php
define( 'SHORTINIT', 1 );
require '../wp-load.php'; // adjust according to your paths
require ABSPATH . WPINC . '/formatting.php';
require ABSPATH . WPINC . '/capabilities.php';
require ABSPATH . WPINC . '/user.php';
require ABSPATH . WPINC . '/meta.php';
require ABSPATH . WPINC . '/post.php';
require ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php';
wp_plugin_directory_constants();
wp_cookie_constants();

if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) { // check capability
  $GLOBALS = array(); // free some memory

  // require your file here

} else {
  header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you G.M. is `wp_plugin_directory_constants` necessary? I was going to use [something almost similar](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/short-init-to-check-if-user-is-logged-in), nice to see this is the way still after 3 years. My WP isn't multi make sense to reset also `WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE`? For cleaning up I was using an `array_keys($GLOBALS)` before and an `array_diff`+`unset` after, but in my case your `$GLOBALS = array();` is amazing :-)

Comment: You need to call `wp_cookie_constants` and this function uses `WP_PLUGIN_URL` constant (see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-includes/default-constants.php#L231) defined by `wp_plugin_directory_constants` function, so if you don't call that function you get a PHP notice for non-defined constant usage, however it isn't a fatal error. Regarding `WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE` you can ignore it if your site is not multisite. @Alex